# Host is unreacheble with static networking configuration via /etc/network/interfaces while GUI NetworkManager is ok

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have some trouble setting-up the network interface using the static IP configuration. I run ubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.11.0-22 with the back-ports enabled.

I followed these [instructions from help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html) but there seems to exist some conflict between the GUI approach (NetworkManager) and the command line approach.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.1.50
gateway 10.1.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 192.168.3.45 192.168.8.10

$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I than try to ping for example google.com `ping -c 3 www.google.com` the response is that the `host is unreachable`. The icon on the top right of the desktop says: wired network disconnected.

If I work using the GUI approach (Edit Connections and so on...) all works great.

Can same one explain to me where I wrong?

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:e6:ba:07:4a:77  
          inet addr:10.1.1.50  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::92e6:baff:fe07:4a77/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19030895 (19.0 MB)  TX bytes:2768769 (2.7 MB)

$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: Is the word geteway misspelled? It is gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gateway is outside of your network

address 10.1.1.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
implies network from 10.1.1.0 - 10.1.1.255

as you can see geteway 10.***0.0***.1 falls outside. Check the subnet on your gateway and assign ip within that range

Comment: Sorry, typing ERROR, I edited the post with the right geteway

Comment: whatdoes `ifconfig -a` return?

Comment: Looks good. Can you get to your gateway? `ping 10.1.1.10` if so maybe it's your dns? ping google at `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: ping 10.1.1.1 looks good while if I ping 8.8.8.8 I get: network is ureachable!! The thing I do not understand is why if I do all these operation via GUI approach all works fine???

Comment: Why are you pinging 10.1.1.1 you're setting the gateway at 10.1.1.10 (10 in the last octet)

Comment: sorry.... i were pinging 10.1.1.10....

Comment: hmmm odd, can you post your routing table `netstat -rn`

Comment: You don't have a route to the internet. Looking closer `geteway 10.1.1.10` you misspelled gAteway

Comment: Now all works! I am very sorry I wasted your time for some stupid typing errors.

Comment: No worries we all been there. Glad i could help. feel free to mark the question solved

Answer (score -3):

You have to remove the network manager

> sudo apt-get remove network-manager

---

> Editor's note:
>
> ***For the love of all that's holy, DO NOT RUN THIS COMMAND!***

Comment: ***DO NOT EVER DO THIS***